# devise in rails 3 : 'user_signed_in?' false 'signed_in?' true 'current_user' nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am migrating a Rails 2 app to Rails 3 and had to use a new authentication solution since restful_authentication is no longer supported. I am trying out Devise and am having problems with it.

I have a login page, which then directs you to the app. You can also use the app without logging in but some options are not available until you login.

Once logging in Devise says that I have logged in via a flash message, but any `current_user` will evaluate to `nil`, `current_user.blank?` evaluates to `true` and any `user_signed_in?` will evaluate to `false`. Oddly `signed_in?` evaluates to `true`. Checking my session data shows that `warden.user.user.id` contains the correct user id and a csrf token exists. This is true both in the view and in the controller.

Here is routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  match "/:controller(/:action(/:id))"  
  match "/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)"
  match "/:controller(/:action(.:format))"

devise_scope :user do
 get 'signup', :to => 'devise/registrations#new'
 get 'login', :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
 get 'signout', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end 
   root :to => 'main#design'

end
```

User.rb

```
require 'digest/sha1'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable, :validatable,
         :encryptable, :encryptor => :restful_authentication_sha1

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_company, :profile_state, :profile_city, :profile_postcode, :profile_country, :profile_phone, :profile_address

  validates_length_of       :name,     :maximum => 100    
  validates_presence_of     :email
  validates_length_of       :email,    :within => 6..100
  validates_uniqueness_of   :email


  def profile_complete?
    if !(self.profile_address.blank? || self.profile_city.blank? || self.profile_state.blank? || self.profile_phone.blank? || self.name.blank? || self.state != 'active')
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

end
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions on SO, but none of the answers seem to fit my scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** `warden.authenticate(:scope => :user)` returns what i would expect `current_user` to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have solved this issue, the restful_authentication plugin added a UsersHelper file that I believe was somehow interfering with how Devise was handling the User class.